# Alternative to exporting to csv export

Tags: csv, export, bulk

I need an alternative to exporting to a csv file.  Basically, the requirement is to be able to allow the user to edit any amount of data from the database.  Currently, the option is to export the data to csv and then the user can update them in Microsoft Excel.  Thus, one can edit it without actually needing to have our web application installed.  However, we are trying to avoid this approach due to some issues we encountered with working with CSV on Excel.  Can someone recommend an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3):

Most programming languages have libraries to allow you to import/export excel directly which avoids many of these issues.  This means you won't have to tell you users to do special Save As when saving their files.

- Java: http://poi.apache.org
- Ruby: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org or http://roo.rubyforge.org

Google can provide options for other languages.

Comment: Is there a microsoft solution for this?  I'm not sure if we can use third party tools.